# How to customize jtable?

Tags: jquery, jtabbedpane, jquery-jtable

I'm new to JTable plugin. I just wanna know is there any other way to create an element whithout using the JTable pop-up? For example when you click the 'Add' button it will get a new row added to the JTable, and there you can add your details and save.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in direct way yet, and the edit inline should be added, but i have no clue why they didn't add it.

Any way you can add extension to do so, just follow the link
https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/issues/302